# What is the opposite of "None of one's business"?

Tags: expressions

If I want to know the connection between A and B.
Can I say

> "What is the business A with B?"

?

Comment: No. From the first sentence in your question, that's not the same. (And it needs to be *business* ***with*** *A* ***and*** *B* to be grammatical.) Why can't you just say, *What's the connection between A and B*? However, if I go by the *title* of your question (which is asking something else), then the opposite of *It's nobody's business* is either *it's somebody's business* or *it's everybody's business*, depending on your interpretation. You should edit your question to make it clear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: “What does this have to do with me?”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What business does A have ...?

Normally the question is asked in a sceptical or even an irate manner.

> What business does she have asking my assistant to run a report for her?

The meaning is, "She has some nerve asking my assistant to do work for her."

If you simply want to know how A and B are involved:

> What is GM's business with Acme Widgets?
>
> What on earth is Tesla's business with Petco?

The usual, most natural way is to use the possessive: *GM's business* or *Tesla's business*

not the periphrastic form with **of**:

*the business of GM with Acme Widgets* <sup>somewhat unnatural</sup>.